# Strange jdownloader ppa package behavior

Tags: installation, 12.10, package-management, ppa, jdownloader

Trying to install Jdownloader like [on this page](https://launchpad.net/~jd-team/+archive/jdownloader)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jdownloader-installer
```

After commands above I get following screen

[image]

Seems well done, but when I search for jdownloader with unity, there is no icon in search results. I removed completely this package with the help of synaptic soft manager several times, and reinstalled. Result is same

What I'm missing?

Comment: @Rinzwind java installed. How to call jd from commandline?

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't need any addon, I ned jd itself

Comment: @Rinzwind When I try commandline method to open jd like `sudo jdownloader` it says there is no such command

Comment: I have the same problem. JDownloader updated today and now I cannot start it anymore. The file /usr/bin/jdownloader is also missing

Comment: It's a problem with the package. I reported the issue to the developer of the PPA and he will fix the problem soon.

Comment: It is fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from the current [buildlog](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/135086029/buildlog_ubuntu-quantal-i386.jdownloader-installer_0.5-0jd2~ubuntu12.10.1~ppa1_UPLOADING.txt.gz) of the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jd-team/+archive/jdownloader/+packages), the script file /usr/bin/jdownloader is not included.

You should notify the maintainer about it: Benjamin Drung bdrung@debian.org

You can also download JDownloader from here:http://jdownloader.org/download/index and choose *Other*.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the PPA version. Important files are missing.

You can also download it [here](http://jdownloader.org/download/index) and choose the under Linux "Download Installer".

After that you have to start the installer:

```
cd /path/to/downloaded/installer
chmod +x jd_unix_0_9.sh
./jd_unix_0_9.sh
```

This will open an installation wizard.

If it asks you for your folder where to install it, choose the folder `/home/<username>/.jdownloader` (make a backup before installation). This will take your existing downloads and configuration settings.

After that you are able to start and use JDownloader again.